# How to center a navbar content of a WordPress underscores menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Have a theme from WordPress underscores and am currently styling it. The only problem now is that for some reason the menu is not aligning to the center as my jsfiddle displays: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/2zjpadys/1/

Html:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content">
   <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">                                
       <div class="menu-menu-container">
          <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
              <li id="menu-item-1753" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-1753">
                   <a href="http://localhost/popperscores/">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1757" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1757">
                   <a href="http://localhost/popperscores/page-b/">ABOUT US</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1761" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1761">
                  <a href="http://localhost/popperscores/about/">OPPORTUNITY</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1762" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1762">
                 <a href="http://localhost/popperscores/level-1/">CONTACT</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
       </div>       
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  width:150px;
  text-decoration:none; 
}
```

All is right expect the alignment. How can I display the menu in the center?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `float: center` from `.main-navigation li` and declaring `display: inline-block` will center the list items of your navigation.

**CSS**

```
.main-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

See snippet below:

```css
.main-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  width:150px;
  text-decoration:none; 
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="site-content">
   <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">                                
       <div class="menu-menu-container">
          <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
              <li id="menu-item-1753" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-1753">
                   <a href="http://localhost/popperscores/">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1757" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1757">
                   <a href="http://localhost/popperscores/page-b/">ABOUT US</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1761" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1761">
                  <a href="http://localhost/popperscores/about/">OPPORTUNITY</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1762" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1762">
                 <a href="http://localhost/popperscores/level-1/">CONTACT</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
       </div>       
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Glad it did!

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me. In a fresh underscores wordpress theme i did:

```
.main-navigation ul {
display: block;
text-align: center; }

.main-navigation li {
float: none !important;
position: relative;
display: inline-block; }
```